# Как обработать событие полного закрытия приложения?

Tags: java, android

Как известно при сворачивании приложение полностью не закрывается (даже если в главном экране успевает отработать `onDestroy`). Однако со временем приложение может быть окончательно закрыто системой или просто вручную.

Вопрос. Какие события при этом возникают и где (помимо `Activity`)? Можно ли перехватить полную остановку приложения (в первую очередь если оно свёрнуто)?

Comment: Насколько я знаю никак. Да и нет в этом практической необходимости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

Если более развернуто, то приложение убивается сигналом `SIGKILL`*(kill)*, который согласно мануалу Linux'а:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

В классе `Application` имеется метод `onTerminate()`, который по идее и есть перехватчик убийства приложения, но в доке написано следующее:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.

Ну то есть метод полная шляпа, работает только в эмуляторе, в продакшне не работает потому как `SIGKILL` не перехватывается.